# Error 1004: While adding Watermark using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, watermark

Hi I'm using this code to add a watermark in excel:

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextEffect(msoTextEffect9, "Bozza","ArialBlack", 36#, msoFalse, msoFalse, 10, 10)
.ScaleWidth 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
.ScaleHeight 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromBottomRight
.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
.Fill.Solid
.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 26
.Fill.Transparency = 0.5
.Shadow.Transparency = 0.5
.Line.Visible = msoFalse
'position at cell corner
.Top = Selection.Top
.Left = Selection.Left
End With
```

but I get an error:

> error 1004: error defined by the application

How can I fix?

Comment: Your code works as is for me, are you sure this is the part getting the error?

Comment: @Warcupine yes when I run this macro I get the error

Comment: I think you have selected more than 1 Sheet. Try Selecting only one sheet and running the code.

Comment: Or change `ActiveSheet` in the start of your code with `Worksheets("Sheet Name")`

Comment: @Mikku you're right, thanks

Comment: @FrancescoBordignon , Cool.. I have added an answer for other people. Accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the Reason is the use of `Activesheet`. You might be selecting multiple sheets and running the code.

You should always avoid using `Activesheet` in VBA. Instead Try referencing them using `Worksheets("Sheet Name")`